# What does "standardized to x%" mean in resveratrol supplements?

Tags: supplement

I read on resveratrol supplements:

[image]

What does "standardized to x%" mean in resveratrol supplements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that whatever the amount of Polygonum cuspidatum Root Extract they used, it contains 50% trans-resveratrol.  But that doesn't help you much since they haven't told you how much Polygonum cuspidatum Root Extract is in the blend.

Compare that to

[image: res]

which says the first capsule it is 99% pure, and the total amount of trans-resveratol is 248 mg.

https://megaresveratrol.net/resveratrol-health-benefits/